# How do we edit comments?

Tags: feature-request, editing, comments

If a comment needs to be amended, how can we edit it? There seems to be no Edit option.

Where is the link to change text?

Comment: This is a comment so I can get a screenshot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just after you've posted a comment, if you hover over the comment text you should see something like this:

[image]

Click 'edit', and you should get the original comment input UI back.

Answer (score 4):

Comments are only editable for 5 minutes, after which the "Edit" option is removed.

See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78573/why-is-the-time-limit-for-editing-comments-only-5-minutes) previous thread on the main SE meta board as to why this is.